# android Log in runnable

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm trying to log a message in a runnable, but it doesn't work. Toast how ever works fine. 
Does Log have some kind of limit too it? I can't find anything about it.

```
private Runnable mPollTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.w("", "3x");
        Toast.makeText(TiltBallActivity.this, "333", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: this seems alright to me...:

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
Log.w(TAG, "index=" + i);
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: It's possible whatever you are viewing logcat with is filtering out messages logged at the "warn" level.

Comment: I've tried Log.e, Log.w Log.d and no difference. No filters on in the logcat either.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm yeah this should work. Try putting a value in the first argument of Log.W. Typically people use the class name. Also make sure your filter in the logcat window is cleared

```
Log.w("ClassName","3x");
```

Comment: Tried, no difference. :(

Comment: Make sure the log filter is set to "Verbose"

Comment: You are sure the toast works? Just wondering if you are actually starting the runnable